# Array of values in FluentD

Tags: arrays, json, fluentd

How to create array of values in the event record with FluentD?

I have parsed latitude and longitude from the log. How to transform these values to an array ?

Ex.
I have a log like

`2014-9-23T09:27:28.345 1411464370345 -37.0081,174.792 BBC SEARCH be03debe-b0af-4939-9abc-7c0ad25bb114 DEPARTURE 16 576.00 ROLLBACK`

I have parsed latitude=-37.0081 and longitude =174.792.
How to form a JSON object like this ?

`{location:[-37.0081,174.792]}`

And how to parse the string value to data types in the event record ? Like integer /float / double

Answer (score 0):

Created array with types parameter of **in_tail** plugin.

`types qty:integer,txamount:float,location:array`

But the array elements are of string type.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following configuration

```
<source>
  type tail
  path stackoverflow.log
  format /^(?<time>[^ ]+) (?<field_1>[^ ]+) (?<array_field>[^ ]+) (?<rest>.+)$/
  time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
  types array_field:array
  tag test
</source>

<match test>
  type stdout
</match>
```

Then, for `2014-9-23T09:27:28.345 1411464370345 -37.0081,174.792 BBC SEARCH be03debe-b0af-4939-9abc-7c0ad25bb114 DEPARTURE 16 576.00 ROLLBACK`, you should see the following output in stdout

```
2014-09-23 09:27:28 +0000 test: {"field_1":"1411464370345","array_field":["-37.0081","174.792"],"rest":"BBC SEARCH be03debe-b0af-4939-9abc-7c0ad25bb114 DEPARTURE 16 576.00 ROLLBACK"}
```

I tested this with Fluentd v0.10.51, but it should work with all recent versions.